# How to retrieve the training history from LinearSVC model?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, svm

I am trying to retrieve the training history of my SVM model to plot its learning curve. Something like:

```
history = model.fit(X, Y, validation_split=0.33, epochs=150, batch_size=10)
```

I have already looked at [GridSearchCV best model CV history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45045666/gridsearchcv-best-model-cv-history) and https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_learning_curve.html to do that, but the first approach did not work for LinearSVC model, and the second approach is not quite what I would like to do (as far as I understood, If I use the learning curve method I will have to train my model again after the grid search).

```
model = GridSearchCV(LinearSVC(verbose=0), 
                              {'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000]}, cv=5, 
                              iid=False, scoring='recall_macro')

model.fit(x_train, y_train)
_, loss, val_loss = learning_curve(model.best_estimator_.fit(X, Y, cv=5))
```

How can I get this history? I am using sklearn 0.20.3.

Comment: I assume `LinearSVC` does not have such a history by default, because SVMs are typically not trained with gradient descent (in contrast to neural networks, which are).

Comment: hmmm, I see. This makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Thinking about it, you can train SVMs with gradient descent using `SGDClassifier(loss="hinge")`. You could then use `partial_fit` to incrementally train your model which naturally gives rise to a learning curve.